# How to get the object's class name when it is an instance of a subclass?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, subclass, classname

Suppose we have an abstract class Animal:

```
function Animal(){};
Animal.prototype.communicate = function(metadata){
   //ABSTRACT
};
```

And then we have a Duck class:

```
function Duck(){};
Duck.prototype = new Animal();
Duck.prototype.communicate = function(metadata){
   console.log("Cuack!");
};
```

So, I'm writting a Greasemonkey script and I really need to save some animals in localstorage to retrieve them the next time the page will be loaded (this way allows me to re-create the same instances I had before reaload page).

So, I really need the classname of every Animal created. I read another similar questions and the way they get the classname is:

```
var aDuck = new Duck();
console.log("ClassName: " + aDuck.constructor.name);
```

But when I do this I get "ClassName: Animal" on console.
P/d: I can't change programming style with prototype, it is a requirement... :(

Any suggestions?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask the object ID it's the same thing that ask object class. The solution is double dispatching. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site. [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 2):

```
Duck.prototype = new Animal();
```

This code is wrong; the correct way to do prototypal inheritance is a little [more complicated](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L544-L567).

If you can't change it directly, you can still fix it in Greasemonkey:

```
Duck.prototype.constructor = Duck;
```

You'll need to do that for each class.

Comment: Thanks SLaks! Could you show me the correct way to do prototypal inheritance? Maybe let me change the way of inheriting :)

Answer (score 2):

The (not perfect, but) **correct way** would be, first calling the `Animal` constructor in `Duck`'s context

```
function Duck() {
    Animal.call(this);
}
```

And then what you did:

```
Duck.prototype = new Animal();
```

And then explicitly making the `Duck`'s instances' constructor point to `Duck`:

```
Duck.prototype.constructor = Duck; 
// so that all new Duck() 's constructor point to Duck
```

PS: Not to offend, the **more complicated** link given by @Slack uses **`Object.create`**, new JavaScript method, to do it. There's no fallback for JavaScript < 1.8. I feel [**OO JS at MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) explains a better (but not perfect) attempt for older JS

`Object.create` has come into picture for this very **inheritance** which you want to achieve (Child class extending the Parent):

```
function inherits(Parent, Child) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = Parent;
    Child.prototype = new F();
}
```

`Object.create` **perfect-izes** the above method, famously known as [Crockford's Prototypal Inheritance Way](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) and implements it natively.
But is available only in modern versions of Browsers (which I know is the major share now)